# How to modify target value in web.config using powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi i am trying to change the values of target in powershell but no luck. 
this is the script which i am using. It works fine to change the app setting values but not the target values

```
$webConfig = 'C:\Users\Desktop\xml\web.config'
$doc = (Get-Content $webConfig) -as [Xml]
$obj = $doc.configuration.targets | where {$_.filename -eq 'test.log.txt'}
$obj.value = 'C:\test_logs\test.log.txt-${shortdate}.log.txt'
$doc.Save($webConfig)
```

I am getting the following error.
The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

This is the web.config

```
<targets>
  <target name="f1" xsi:type="File" fileName="test.log.txt" layout="${threadname} ${longdate}  
${callsite} ${logger}[${level}] ${message}" />
  <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${threadname} ${longdate} ${callsite}   
${logger}[${level}] ${message}" />
</targets>
```

edited script
    $webConfig = 'C:\Users\Desktop\xml\web.config'
    $doc = (Get-Content $webConfig) -as [Xml]
    $obj = $doc.configuration.targets.target | where {$_.fileName -eq 'test.log.txt'}
    $obj.SetAttribute'C:\test_logs\test.log.txt-${shortdate}.log.txt'
    $doc.Save($webConfig)

Answer (score 0):

$obj is empty you missed 'target' property

```
$obj = $doc.configuration.targets | foreach { $_.target } | where { $_.fileName...
```

Or in v3:

```
$obj = $doc.configuration.targets.target | where { $_.fileName -and $_.fileName -eq..
```

Comment: i am getting this error message ,when i use the above code

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. i have modified the script in question

Answer (score 0):

Try [SetAttribute(string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw.aspx) instead. I've encountered problems with using the magic properties PowerShell sets up for attributes/sub-elements:

```
$obj.SetAttribute( 'value', 'C:\test_logs\test.log.txt-${shortdate}.log.txt' )
```

This will also work if the `value` attribute is missing.